# In regards to ARC, in the following code does Kraken have a strong reference to Sucker?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I'm reading about ARC in Swift to get a better understanding of memory allocation and deallocation.  In the following blog I'm excerpt I'm reading from, I understand that Kraken has a strong reference to Tentacle and then Tentacle has a strong reference to Sucker however I'm curious to know if Kraken has a strong relationship to Sucker?

Here is the code:

```
class Kraken {
    let tentacle = Tentacle() //strong reference to child.
}
class Tentacle {
    let sucker = Sucker() //strong reference to child
}
class Sucker {}
```

Comment: Indirect (transitive) references like this don't count towards the strong reference counts. Only direct ones do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it hasn't. The reference count for `sucker` object is still **1**. The moment `Kraken` cut loose his `tentacle`, the `sucker` will go away as well ;)

In other words, *indirect strong references* won't increase the ref counter used by the ARC memory manager.

A quick test:

```
let kraken = Kraken()
let refCount = CFGetRetainCount(kraken.tentacle.sucker)
print("ref count: \(refCount)")
```

outputs:

> ref count: 2

which you should read as `1`, since it includes the reference retained by `CFGetRetainCount` function *argument* as well.